# How to avoid exception when checking not defined var?

Tags: javascript

Simple question but i'm stuck for a while on it.

I need to check if a var is defined, before execute some taks.

So i try this

```
if (myVar !== null) alert('myVar is not null');
```

But when i do this and myVar is not defined, an exception is threw :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myVar is not defined at :1:1

So how to solve this dilema ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type of

```js
if (typeof variable !== 'undefined') alert('myVar is not null');
```

Comment: Thanks for helping instead of minus the topic. Simple solution, thanks ! :D

Comment: @delphirules you're welcome.